# Automated tools to manage or monitor authorized_keys?

Tags: ssh

**In short**

Are there any tools that can be used to work with authorized_keys to scan the keys and maintain a database of which servers have which keys?

**More context**

I'm a big fan of public key authentication for ssh, but one aspect that worries me a bit is disabling keys that are compromised. I've been putting my laptop public key on all the servers I interact with. I've been doing this for years. I've long since lost track of all the servers I've put the key on.

In the event that my laptop is stolen, proper procedure would be to remove that public key from everywhere I've added it. But, like I said, I can't remember where that is.

I'm wondering if there are any automated tools that help with this, like something that maintains a database of where your key is, and helps you to remove it in the case where a key is lost.

Pie-in-the-sky would be a daemon that runs on each server and periodically checks with a remote database. If it finds any keys have been flagged, it immediately removes them from all authorized_keys files that it monitors. However, with a daemon editing authorized_keys, I'm sure there are all kinds of ways that could be exploited, so even a step down where it just somehow notifies you, saying "Hey, I've got a compromised key here..." would be better.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not want to promote commercial software, I know [ssh.com](http://www.ssh.com) is selling a software called "Universal SSH Key manager" that can discover, monitor, remidiate and manage SSH keys throughout an enterprise.

They describe their product with the following quote:

> Your enterprise may have more Secure Shell identities than employees.
>   A lot more. Gain visibility and control over who has access to what
>   and when, with the only comprehensive identity and access management
>   solution for Secure Shell.

I have not tried their software, and are not affiliated with them.
It would be interesting to see if anyone can recommend open tools that do more or less the same task.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like pretty much what I was asking for, but when I read "enterprise" and there's no pricing displayed, I know it's waaaay out of my range.